# Is it possible to add another Off-Topic close reason?

Tags: discussion, closing, allowed-questions

The current OT close reasons show several options, but one key reason is missing: *blatantly Off-Topic*.

I have tried to fetch some numbers from Data, but I can only access comments that are not deleted (so no deleted comments on deleted questions), which show around 60 out of 210 close reasons are about being blatantly OT.

We have quite a lot of questions closed for this and it would make things a lot easier. Or is there a reason why we don't have an option for this?

Comment: simply use the "Other" close reason and type *"I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's blatantly Off-Topic"*. though personally *"I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with video games"* would be better

Comment: @Memor-X I know how to do that, but the question is about a shortcut reason.

Comment: Point of reference for other plebs who show up here and wonder what this is about: the flagging UI dialogue changes when you reach 3k rep ([so you can cast close and reopen votes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)). For those of us that have not reached that point yet, you **can** still flag questions as *"Blatantly off-topic"*

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible.

There are only a limited number of close-reasons available and we're at that number. Changing that number can only be done by Stack Exchange.

Comment: We also have to have a pretty compelling reason to increase that number. "Because it's not about video games" isn't.

Comment: @Unionhawk you're right that need a compelling reason, but it's not really based on the merit of close reason  itself. It has more to do with just how many questions would be closed with that new reason. If 30% of all closed questions were just "blatantly off-topic" since they're asking about quilting and automobiles then that's a pretty solid case for making it a close reason.

Comment: We don't have that problem mind you, so we don't need the reason, but you get the idea.

Comment: @Wipqozn so we need an actual problem to get something useful? Almost 1/4 of the custom text is about "not gaming" (according to what's available on Data), so it's quite a number... while not having it is not a real problem it would certainly be a good addition to have it... Not everyone uses auto-text addons.